# How is that Popen creates an asynchronous stream and how to replicate it

Tags: python, async-await, io, subprocess

When you write

```
p = subprocess.Popen('some command')
for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, b''):
  print(line)
```

You obtain the following behavior:

- The `for` loop won't exit until the subprocess is done.
- If the process is not generating new lines, the for loop will simply wait until there is either a new line or the process is done.

These seem to be properties that if you tried to mimic you would have to make use of `async/await`, but `subprocess.Popen` gives you this behavior without needing them.The iterator from the `iter(p.stdout.readline, b'')` part seems to be event driven (it only triggers if there is something new). A regular iterator does not wait (at least not as smartly and without a blind `time.sleep`).

Is there something special about `subprocess.Popen` that makes this possible? If not, is it possible to mimic a `BufferedReader` like `subprocess.Popen.stdout`?

For example, if I wanted to take the output of a process and live-stream it to two different threads, I would somehow have to replicate the original `BufferedReader` into two, but it is not clear to me how would you replicate the "waiting" behavior on the two resulting `BufferedReader`'s.

Comment: `for line in iter(input, ''): ` would give you the same behaviour, do you see anything special in this case?

Comment: Yes! I guess my question would be, if I wanted to create my own BufferedReader what would I need to do so that it keeps waiting until the buffer is closed? Would I have to do something at the implementation readline() level?